# Is there any way to use curly braces as function parameters without including any other header file in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

When I try to send something like `{1,2,3,4,5}` as a parameter to a function, I have to use `std::vector` or `std::initializer_list` or an STL container. I searched this topic, everyone were using `initializer_lis` or STL containers as function parameters for sending curly-brace arguments. I couldn't find any other way to do it.

Is there any other way of sending parameters as curly braces without adding a header file?

Comment: `struct Foo { int x; double y; std::string z; };  Foo foo = {5, 12.3, "Hello" };`

Comment: @Eljay yeah i also tried that. But if we look at the stl containers there are no limit for the values, right ? i mean if i use this structure i can only give 3 variables in function. in vector class you can give as much as you want. vector<int>x {1,2,3,4,5.....}

Comment: `std::vector` uses `std::initializer_list`. If that's the tool you're after, you need to include it.

Comment: @chris yes but what std::initializer_list uses for it's own constructor ? I dont think it's a pure C++ feature.

Comment: @AytuncDemir, It uses compiler magic. It's a language feature represented through a special library interface. (I seem to remember both GCC and Clang injecting a call to its constructor with either two pointers or a pointer and size as arguments.)

Comment: @AytuncDemir `std::initializer_list` is part of the language. Its public interface is defined by the standard, but its construction is implemented by the compiler itself.

Comment: You could probably use something like `1,2,3,4,5` (without the curly brackets),use C style varargs, and assume those are ints while traversing those varargs, which is obviously dangerous, but why would you? Using `std::vector<int>` or `std::list<int>` seems like a perfectly valid, nice and safe way to do this.

Comment: @AytuncDemir: "*without adding a header file?*" Why is the presence of a header file so unpleasant to you? It's among the smallest headers the C++ standard library has.

Comment: @NicolBolas i just want to learn structure of initializer_list. Now i learned it's C++'s part.

Comment: There are other core language features that have the core language feature's API declared in a header file rather than baked into the core language.  For example, `typeid` and `#include <typeinfo>` for `std::type_info`; or `new` and `#include <new>` for `std::bad_alloc`.  The C++ standard library is intimately *part* of C++.  Some parts of the C++ standard library header files have special compiler support, e.g., the `offsetof` (in `<cstddef>`) may require special compiler support or internal compiler knowledge to guarantee behavior for what would otherwise be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list initialization with arrays, which don't require any headers. For example:

```
template <int N>
int sum(int const (& array)[N]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : array) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    return sum({1,2,3});
}
```

The disadvantage of arrays compared to `std::vector` is that the size of the array has to be fixed or passed as a template argument.